# React-Native error: Unable to Resolve Module '/screen/Welcome' from 'index.js':

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

How can I solve this problem?

I just wanted to use the Router to switch screens  but
I got this error on ios emulator:
[error screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcPGR.png)
Structure: [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoUC9.png)

```
[Sun Aug 16 2020 01:36:26.597]  BUNDLE  ./index.js 

error: Error: Unable to resolve module `/screens/Welcome` from `index.js`: 

None of these files exist:
  * ../../../../screens/Welcome(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * ../../../../screens/Welcome/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/erenberkay/Desktop/app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/erenberkay/Desktop/app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/erenberkay/Desktop/app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/erenberkay/Desktop/app/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at /Users/erenberkay/Desktop/app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:434:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/erenberkay/Desktop/app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
    at /Users/erenberkay/Desktop/app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/erenberkay/Desktop/app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

index.js

```
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './App';
    import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Welcome.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

export default class Welcome extends React.Component {

    render(){

        return(

  <View style={styles.container}>

    <Text>Welcome</Text>
    
  </View>
    
    )

    }

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

container: {
flex:1,
backgroundColor:'yellow',
alignItems:'center',
justifyContent:'center'


}
  
});
```

App.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  ImageBackground,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import Router from './src/Router';
import EntypoIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/Entypo";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render(){

  return(<Router/>)

  }

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

container: {
flex:1,
backgroundColor:'yellow',
alignItems:'center',
justifyContent:'center'


}
  
});
```

Router.js

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    createSwitchNavigator,
    createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';

import Welcome from '/screens/Welcome';
import Register from 'screens/Register';
import Login from '/screens/Login';

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {

        Welcome: {
            screen : Welcome
        },

        Register: {
            screen : Register
        },

        Login: {
            screen : Login
        }

    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Welcome'
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```

versions

- "react": "16.13.1",
- "react-native": "0.63.2",
- "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
- "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
- "react-navigation": "^4.4.0"

Comment: How is the structure of the project?

Comment: Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoUC9.png

Comment: how is Router class?

Comment: I edited the post and added Router.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all these from

```
import Welcome from '/screens/Welcome';
import Register from 'screens/Register';
import Login from '/screens/Login';
```

to

```
import Welcome from './screens/Welcome';
import Register from './screens/Register';
import Login from './screens/Login';
```

You may share your folder structure for more clarity

Comment: thanks, but now I got another error :  https://i.imgur.com/ObtXftU.png

Comment: From where are you referencing that file?

Answer (score 1):

add package.json in your screens folder with only

```
{
    "name": "@screens"
}
```

and then import your screems like

```
import Welcome from "@screens/Welcome";
```